# NAT Public IP to Public IP with Mikrotik

Tags: firewall, routing, router, nat, mikrotik

My target is to route: 192.0.2.1 (public IP) to 192.0.2.2 (another public IP out of my network). I want to route all the ports and protocols, so Mikrotik will just send all the packets there.

I have tried this:

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dst-nat dst-address=192.0.2.1 \ action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.0.2.2

/ip firewall nat add chain=src-nat dst-address=192.0.2.2 \ action=masquerade
```

However it didn't work. May I please know what I'm doing wrong? I should point out that 192.0.2.1 is not connected to any server out there, however 192.0.2.1/24 is in use on the router and some IP's are in use on the servers.

Comment: You onlyu use NAT if you must translate between private and public addresses, or you have overlapping addresses. By the way, [IANA has set aside multiple address ranges for examples](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`), and you should use those so that people know you are faking addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin I generally need to configure reverse proxy from one IP to another (all ports), and I'm trying to find a way. If you can help, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I wouldn't recommend that kind of approach to solve, and there are a lot of reasons why: networking issues, performance issues, troubleshooting issues, and so on.

I would try solving that initially with a DNS name resolution or, if it's just a web application, a reverse proxy inside your network (if that's the case, that could also be solved using the DNS approach).

But if you really wanna solve it through RouterOS, try this:

https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=96996

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. The top command works using [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables), which is relatively simple in this case as it is for all traffic between two IPs

`# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.0.2.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.0.2.2`

In 'Microtik' format it is:

`/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat action=dst-nat src-address=192.0.2.1 dst-address=192.0.2.1 to-addresses=192.0.2.2`

Comment: This answer, despite beeing correct imho, is a bit short and has no explanation; try to add some more info to make it useful for as many people as possible.

Comment: Expanded to include what command is doing :)

Comment: User is using RouterOS, not iptables.

Comment: @StefanoMartins corrected